# Ошибка при записи в базу

Tags: php, mysql

Собираю данные из формы и закидываю в базу. Часть данных необходимо просто сериализовать. Но вот беда, mysql кидает ошибку... не могу понять, что ему не нравится в сериализованных данных

```
$prop = serialize($elements['prop']);
$prop = addslashes($prop);
$sql = 'insert into iblocks(name,code,desct,serialize) values('.$elements['name'].','.$elements['code'].','.$elements['desc'].','.$prop.')';
```

Ошибка:

> `corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':2:{i:0;a:5:{s:4:\"name\";s:3:\"sdf\";s:4:\"code\";s:3:\"sfd\";s:4:\"type\";s:3:' at line 1`

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите строку запроса в двойные кавычки. Да и строки в запросе лучше обрамлять кавычками. Раз уж не пользуетесь плейсхолдерами.

```
 $sql = "insert into iblocks(name,code,desct,serialize) 
     values('".$elements['name']."','"
    .$elements['code']."','".$elements['desc']."','".$prop."')";
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало

Answer (score 0):

А еще лучше вот так сделать с переменными, из которых составляется запрос

> `$prop = mysql_real_escape_string($prop);`

Comment: А еще лучше использовать-таки PDO и плейсхолдеры (функции `mysql_*` deprecated, алло). Чай не в 90-х живем.